# Factor pairs problem

Tags: factoring

Is it possible to find a number $N$ such that it has two factor pairs {a,b}, {c,d} such that (a+1)(b+1)=(c+1)(d+1)

My intuition tells me this is impossible in the case where a,b,c,d are positive integers. However I’m curious if this is still true for negative $N$ too. For negative $N$, assume $a$ and $c$ are negative.

Comment: Such as $N = 12$? $a=1$, $b=5$, $c=2$, $d=3$? Or are you wanting to have $ab=cd=N$ as well?

Comment: my reading has it as a,b,c,d aren't choosen but found.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What would be the difference between finding a,b,c,d with the property, and choosing a,b,c,d with the property?

Comment: it specifically states factor pairs ...

Comment: If such a thing did occur, we'd have to have two pairs of numbers with same geometric and arithmetic means. That's because, the product is defined the same, so their geometric mean on an equal number of inputs is the same. However the difference of the $$(a+1)(b+1)=(c+1)(d+1)$$ is such that  $a+b=c+d$ meaning that both pairs have the same geometric mean and arithmetic, producing the same arithmetic-geometric mean

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I like your arithmetic and geometric observations. That seems like a useful route into this problem. I’ll give that line of reasoning some thought.

Comment: all it would take is a unique agm per pair to disprove existence.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee If that means that $ab = cd = N$, I did ask for clarification about that ...

Comment: yeah but your first part wasn't remotely related to the question. it specifically stated factor pairs.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Sorry, I thought that had been addressed. Since a and b are a factor pair, ab=N. Since c and d are a factor pair, cd=N. hence ab=cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a, b, c, d, N \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $N = ab = cd$. Suppose that $(a+1)(b+1) = (c+1)(d+1)$.

Expanding $(a+1)(b+1) = (c+1)(d+1)$ we get that $a+b = c + d$.

Now substituting $b = \frac{N}{a}$ and $d = \frac{N}{c}$ we get $a+\frac{N}{a} = c + \frac{N}{c}$.

Rearranging we have $(a-c)(ac-N)=0$ and using that $N =ab$ we get $(a-c)(c-b) = 0$.

Hence the only solution is $\{a, b\} = \{c, d\}$.